# Difference between NSNotification and NSEvent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotification, nsevent

I don't really understand the difference that cocoa makes between a notification and an event.

For instance I could have code like this:

```
-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)event { … }
```

but not

```
-(void)windowMoved:(NSEvent*)event { … }
```

For the second one I'd have to use `NSNotification`  –  why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is, that NSEvent is used to encapsulate input events. Mouse down, key down etc.
However, NSNotification is used to notify observers about a change of a state or an object (eg. when the network reachability changed, new data became available or that a window moved).

In your case: A window move isn't some kind of input, but a change of the windows position. Thus you get an NSNotification rather an NSEvent.

Comment: But why shall it be good to make a difference between input event and change of a state? Doesn't that make life unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: @Polybos: Because there are two different concepts behind them. A NSNotification is published to anyone who is interested in this state change, but a NSEvent is only send to the current top most receiver (the object with the focus). A NSEvent isn't meant to be broadcasted through the whole application, but that exactly what a NSNotification is made for.